# refresh component on Save issue

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to refresh my LWC when the save function is triggered.
I tried as suggested in other post to use refreshApex(this.retrievedCurrendData)
but nothing seems to work.
I tried as well with a return. The data is saved .. but I need to reload the page completely to have it work

```
handleSave(){
    console.log("Saving...")
    this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saving...'
    this.updatedData['Id'] = this.recordData.Id
    let toSaveList = this.updatedData
    UW_SavedData({records : toSaveList}).then(() => {  
        refreshApex(this.retrievedCurrendData)
        refreshApex(this.propertyMarketList)          
        this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saved';
        
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title : 'Success',
                message : `Data saved succesfully!`,
                variant : 'success',
            }),
        )
                  
        this.isEdited = false;
        this.error = undefined;
        //return refreshApex(this._wiredOData2)
        
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.record = undefined;
        //console.log("Error in Save call back:", this.error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        //refreshApex(this.estimatedOccupencyData);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Save';
        }, 3000);
    }); 
    

}

_wiredOData;
    @wire(getRecordData,{currentRecordId: '$recordId'})
    retrievedCurrendData(wireResult){
        const { data, error } = wireResult;
        this._wiredOData = wireResult;
        if(data){
            console.log("PropData", data)
            this.recordData = data
            this.final_rate = data.ADR_USD__c * 0.85;
            this.propertyMarket = data.Market__c
            this.marketOccupency = data.Market__r.Market_Occupancy__c
            this.propertyNumberOfKeys = data.Number_of_Keys__c
            this.PropertyKeysReviewRatio = data.Number_of_Reviews__c / data.Number_of_Keys__c
            this.Booking_rating = data.Booking_com_Rating__c * 2
            this.ReadinessScore = data.Readiness_Score__c
            this.propertyLocationScore = data.Location_Score__c
            this.isRestaurant = data.Restaurant__c,
            this.isBar = data.Bar__c,
            this.isMeetingRooms = data.meeting_rooms__c, 
            this.isBeachFront = data.Beachfront__c, 
            this.isRooftop = data.Rooftop__c, 
            this.isPool = data.Pool__c
        }

        if(error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ben2pop, could you please post how do you set those properties you're passing to `refreshApex`?

Comment: @RubenDG I added it

Comment: The only refreshApex you need is `refreshApex(this._wiredOData)` , but the one commented in your code is `refreshApex(this._wiredOData2)`, with a **2** at the end. If it is not a typo, most likely it's the culprit.

Comment: tried it .. nothing changed. this._wiredOData2 is used as well I need to refresh both

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code, It works.

```
import { updateRecord  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'; //Imported updateRecord from uiRecordApi
```

Js Method:

In updateRecord  passing recordId as a field.

```
 refreshLightningPage() {   // Here refresh lightning page is a method
   updateRecord({fields: { Id: this.recordId }});
   }
```

You can call refreshLightningPage after getting success from save button,like below

```
 this.refreshLightningPage();
```

Comment: There is no way to refreesh only the component and not the page ?

Comment: have you tried above code?

Comment: I added this.refreshLightningPage(); after this.toggleSaveLabel = 'Saved'; and I added a console log in refreshLightningPage() . So it is printing console.log('refreshing', this.recordId) in my console but nothing is reloading it stay the same ..